# PHPUnit ReturnCallback when using cloned objects

Tags: php, callback, phpunit, clone

I am finding extremely difficult to modify mock objects that are cloned by the class I am testing.
Here is my test:

```
    $firstDocument = array('type' => 'venue', 'name'=> "first venue");

    $venueContent = $this->getMockBuilder('My\Class\Namespace\VenueContent')->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();

    $setValues = function($document) use(&$venueContent){
        $venueContent->expects($this->any())->method('getDocument')->will($this->returnValue($document));
        $venueContent->expects($this->any())->method('getName')->will($this->returnValue($document->name));
    };

    $venueContent->expects($this->any())->method('setDocument')->will($this->returnCallback($setValues));

    $this->object = new ContentFactory();
    $this->object->registerContentType('venue', $venueContent);

    $firstVenue = $this->object->create($firstDocument);
```

This is the ContentFactory class:

```
class ContentFactory
{
/**
 * @var array classMap
 */
private $contentTypes = array();

/**
 * Register a document map for use in creating & validating documents
 * @param string $name
 * @param array $type
 */
public function registerContentType($name, $type)
{
    $this->contentTypes[$name] = $type;
}

/**
 * Create & validate a document
 * @param array $document
 * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
 * @return ContentInterface
 */
public function create(array $document)
{
    if (!isset($document['type'])) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Unknown content type');
    }
    $documentType = $document['type'];

    if (!\array_key_exists($documentType, $this->contentTypes)) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Unmapped content service');
    }
    $contentModel = clone $this->contentTypes[$documentType];
    $contentDocument = $this->createContentDocument($document);

    $contentModel->setDocument($contentDocument);

    return $contentModel;
}

/**
 * Create underlying ContentDocument
 * @param array $document
 * @return ContentDocument
 */
private function createContentDocument($document)
{
    return new ContentDocument($document);
}
}
```

My problem is that everytime I do a `clone` of the object, I cannot modify it in the callback of the test because the object I am passing in the USE statement is the original object (the one I use to clone).
Does anybody know how the callback can access the caller object so that I can modify it no matter what instance it is without using `debug_backtrace`?

Comment: Why do you clone the contentModel? Why not just using the existing one? If this is for whatever reason important for you and you will keep this behaviour, I would suggest to add a method `getContentModel()` which could be mocked in tests.